# How to automatically extend /home partition to use free space at end of disk?

Tags: partitioning

I have created a golden image of Ubuntu 20.04 on a 25mb virtual disk, with the partitions as follows:

```
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda: 26.8GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number    Start    End      Size    Type      File system      Flags
 1        1049kB   512MB    511MB   primary   linux-swap(v1)   boot
 2        513MB    26.8GB   26.3GB  extended
 5        513MB    1012MB   499MB   logical   ext4
 6        1013MB   16.0GB   15.0G   logical   ext4
 7        16.0GB   26.8GB   10.8GB  logical   ext4
```

`/dev/vda6` is `/root` and `/dev/vda7` is `/home`.

This disk gets exported out as an image for virtual machines to be created from. I'm trying to create a script that will run on the first boot of a newly created virtual machine that will extend the home partition to use the available free space at the end of the disk, but I'm not getting the results I'm expecting.

I followed [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436069) and created the following files on the golden image disk before exporting:

`/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

type /etc/init.d/extend-home-part.sh && /etc/init.d/extend-home-part.sh

exit 0
```

`/etc/init.d/extend-home-part.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo growpart /dev/vda 7 && sudo resize2fs /dev/vda7
sudo mv /etc/init.d/extend-home-part.sh /etc/init.d/extended-home-part.sh

exit 0
```

After I created a virtual machine with a larger virtual disk, I can see that the script ran because the script has been renamed, but the /home partition hasn't changed. `parted print free` gives this output:

```
(parted) print free
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk: /dev/vda: 172GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number    Start    End      Size    Type      File system      Flags
          32.3kB   1049kB   1016kB            Free Space
 1        1049kB   512MB    511MB   primary   linux-swap(v1)   boot
          512MB    513MB    1048kB            Free Space
 2        513MB    26.8GB   26.3GB  extended
 5        513MB    1012MB   499MB   logical   ext4
          1012MB   1013MB   70kB              Free Space
 6        1013MB   16.0GB   15.0G   logical   ext4
          16.0GB   16.0GB   639kB             Free Space
 7        16.0GB   26.8GB   10.8GB  logical   ext4
          26.8GB   172GB    145GB             Free Space
```

When I try to run the commands manually on the new virtual machine, I get this output:

```
$ sudo growpart /dev/vda 7
CHANGED: partition=7 start=31275008 old: size=21151744 end=52426752 new: size=304269279 end=335544287

$ sudo resize2fs /dev/vda7
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 2643968 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!
```

The free space at the end still remains unused, and `parted print free` output doesn't change. I don't understand why the `/home` partition doesn't extend, even after manually running the commands.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to execute this task?

Note: I know it is possible to use the Disks utility in Ubuntu to resize the `/home` partition, but we do not want virtual machine users having to do this every time they create a new Ubuntu VM. Automating this process is the necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDOS partition table is limited to four primary partitions. More partitions require one primary partition be an extended partition, which may hold many logical partitions. You cannot expand a logical partition beyond the extended partition. Either use GPT partitioning or extend partition 2 first. Expanding on the right may be possible with a mounted partition, check the tool man pages -- gparted can, don't know about growpart.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with MBR like I am with GPT and rarely use logical partitions. Simply changing my script to `sudo growpart /dev/vda 2 && sudo growpart /dev/vda 7 && sudo resize2fs /dev/vda7` made everything work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I see your VM's space size is 172GB, but your VM's disk space size is 26.8GB.

All you need to do is to expand the extended partition `/dev/vda2`, expand the logical partition `/dev/vda7` and resize the file type of the expanded`/dev/vda7`.

I recommend using `cfdisk` to do that,

1. Just use `sudo cfdisk` to enter the power of `cfdisk`, using the up and down direction buttons to choose your partitions, using the right and left direction buttons to choose your operations, e.g:

   1. resize `/dev/vda2` to 171.5GB with start cylinder 513MB and end cylinder 172GB
   2. resize `/dev/vda7` to 156GB with start cylinder 16GB and end cylinder 172GB
2. Resize your new extended logical partition `/dev/vda7`: `sudo resize2fs /dev/vda7`.
3. Restart or reboot your VM: `sudo reboot`.

Your idea, "Simply changing my script to `sudo growpart /dev/vda 2 && sudo growpart /dev/vda 7 && sudo resize2fs /dev/vda7` made everything work perfectly!" is great!

That helped me avoid expanding my VM's disk space every time I create a new Debian VM.

Also, your Automatic idea is fantastic! Thanks!